# SketchUp C++ equivalent API to Ruby's ShadowInfo

Tags: sketchup

Is there an equivalent C++ API in SkechUp SDK for its Ruby's API to obtain ShadowInfo?

Mainly I am trying to get the direction of the Sun as set from the Shadow Setting.

If it is not there, is there any other API that can help in deducing this info eg Day/Time/Year?

Comment: Do you actually using the old C++ SDK? Or are you using the new C API?

Answer (score 0):

That feature is currently missing but, we do have a feature request filed to add it.

Bryce

Product Manager, SketchUp Extensibility Team